# Abbreviation meaning of heading of BO on deaths reported in NYC record

Tags: death-records, new-york-city, 1950s

My brother died on March 17, 1953.  On record I found for Deaths report in NYC, there was a heading of BO and for my brother a Y was entered in that column.  How can I find out what that all means?

Answer (score 5):

According to the legend at the bottom of the page, **BO** stands for **BO**RO (borough). The possible values are **M**: Manhattan, **X**: Bronx, **K**: Brooklyn, **Q**: Queens, **R**: Richmond (Staten Island), **Z**: at sea, and **Y**: out of city.

The legend for age is **N**: minutes, **H**: hours, **D**: days, **L**: months.

[image: NYC death index BO column]
[image]